# How to assure interval function is called again when all async functions are done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Let's say I have this function:

```
var iv = setInterval(async() => {
  //timeconsuming calls
  await someFunction();
}, 8000);
```

I want to call `someFunction()` only if all async calls are finished. Inside `someFunction` I have calls like this:

```
async someFunction(){
  await call1()
  await call2()
  await call3()
}
```

How can I can achieve this? Should I use instead of `setInterval` a function that returns a `boolean` if all functions are finished? How can I achieve this? should I use `Promise.all()` function to wait for all async functions?

Comment: I'd recommend not using `setInterval` in this case because you're not looking for a function call after an interval, you're looking for more complex scheduling.

Comment: If you could explain as to why use `setInterval`. In other words what is making you use `setInterval`

Comment: i want to start the somefunction every time when its finished. @brimble2010 how should I schedule this kind of tasks?

Comment: Use recursive function. After `someFunction` executed put a setTimeout and call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a `setTimeout` function that calls itself recursively once the calls are done:

```js
const call1 = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200));
const call2 = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200));
const call3 = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200));
async function someFunction() {
  await call1();
  await call2();
  await call3();
}

const timeoutFn = async () => {
  console.log('iteration');
  await someFunction();
  setTimeout(timeoutFn, 8000);
  console.log('new timeout set');
};

timeoutFn();
```

Comment: okay I see. Will this assure that someFunction() will not called in intervall if it takes more than 8 seconds to complete? It will just start someFunction() after 8 seconds after finishing, right?

Comment: `It will just start someFunction() after 8 seconds after finishing` Exactly

Comment: Okay nice approach, just to do a hierarchical recursive call. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like the following -

```
function someFunction() {
    Promise.all([promiseCall1, promiseCall2, promiseCall3]).then(values => {
        if(!breakCondition)
            someFunction();
    });
}
```

Have not tested it though.